# Lower bound. How and why is it working: let mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1)

Tags: rust

please tell me how this line (`let mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1);`) works in this code? Why is she similar to this (`let mid = left + ((right - left) / 2);`), but it works faster?

The whole code:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
impl Solution {
    pub fn search_insert(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> i32 {
        let (mut left, mut right) = (0, nums.len());
        while left < right {
            let mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1);
            match nums[mid].cmp(&target) {
                Ordering::Less => left = mid + 1,
                _ => right = mid,
            }
        }
        left as _
    }
}
```

I don't know where to look for an explanation for this.

Comment: In the given code, all of the variables are unsigned, so there shouldn't be a difference between bit shift and integer division, right? The compiler should be able to optimize the `/ 2` into `>> 1`?

Comment: It's a micro-optimization. Twenty years ago, it might've saved a handful of clock cycles. Today, the compiler is smarter than you, so you should write readable code and let the compiler decide if it makes sense to do bit-shifting instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "works faster"? Have you benchmarked this (in release mode), or what else is this claim based off? Seeing as the assembly is the same (as it should be, since this is unsigned arithmetic), they should be equally fast.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'd be careful with such a general statement. For signed integers, I wouldn't bet on the compiler always being able to prove that an expression is guaranteed to be positive (and otherwise, shifts and integer division aren't equivalent, ex. `-1 >> 1` vs `-1 / 2`, though the compiler will still probably replace divisions by powers of two with a bitop tricks, just not a single arithmetic shift, it takes more than that for equivalence with idiv). In this case the integers in question are unsigned (which I initially missed, oof) so everything is fine, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The theory

Using bitwise shifts for divisions by powers of two is a common programming "trick" and not unique to Rust.

`let mid = left + ((right - left) / 2)` finds the middle index between `left` and `right`: You take the `left` index, and add half the distance between the two indices, rounded down (integer division).

`>> 1` on signed integers is an arithmetic bitwise right shift by one: You take the lowest bit and throw that out, and fill the highest bit with the sign bit. For signed integers >= 0, the sign bit will be 0, so you'll just be "shifting out" the lowest bit. This is equivalent to a floor division by two (2¹). More generally, shifting right by n is equivalent to floor division by 2^n for unsigned integers or signed integers >= 0.

Thus, `(right - left) / 2` is equivalent to `(right - left) >> 1` since `right >= left` holds here.

The Rust compiler knows that this most hold, because `right` and `left` are `usize`, and thus `right - left` is `usize` too, so all arithmetic that is happening here is unsigned and `/ 2` and `>> 1` are fully equivalent.

(If they were signed integers, it would have to prove that your integers will never be negative, forcing it to emit an actual integer division otherwise, because arithmetic shifting and integer division are not equivalent: In two's complement, -1 is a bitpattern of all ones. Shift that right arithmetically by one, and you still have all ones due to the sign extension, so `-1 >> 1` is still -1, thus "optimizing" signed integer division to a shift in general would be wrong.)

By explicitly using the shift yourself, you tell the Rust compiler that you do not mind this behavior. Otherwise, the compiler may only apply this optimization if it can prove that `right >= left` (which it trivially can here, though).

Note that - assuming there's no risk of overflow from computing `left + right` (e.g. only on 64-bit, so **not an option** for the `usize`s here, thanks to commenters for making me aware of this) - there is a simpler way to find the middle index: `left + (right - left) / 2` is equivalent to `(left + right) / 2`, since we have `(left + right) / 2 = (2*left + (right - left)) / 2 = left + (right - left) / 2`. Using this, I can get slightly shorter assembly, but I haven't benchmarked it. I'd expect it to be faster and at worst equally fast, though.

That's the theory, at least.

### The practice

> but it works faster?

In practice, I can find no evidence for this claim. I churned both [the shift version](https://godbolt.org/z/bM3c7aWG3) and [the integer division version](https://godbolt.org/z/q7znxn1e9) through Godbolt and the output is *exactly identical assembly*. From this we can conclude that (1) Rust *is* able to prove that integer division and shift are equivalent here (because left, right are >= 0), and (2) **there is no advantage to using `>> 1` instead of `/ 2` here, Rust applies this "optimization" for you**.

Comment: *However, the Rust compiler can't necessarily prove that your integers will never be negative* - in the OP's snippet, `left` and `right` are `usize`, which is unsigned.

Comment: @user4815162342 you're completely right. I had just seen `i32` in the signature (but those are completely unrelated, of course) and initially worked under the OP's assumption of a performance difference (which integer division vs. shifting could have conveniently explained)... Could you tell that I'm used to languages where `left` and `right` would be signed ints? :-)

Comment: *I had just seen i32 in the signature (but those are completely unrelated, of course)* - the `i32` return value isn't completely unrelated, as it would normally determine the type of `left` at least. But there's a sneaky `as _` cast that does the trick. It's so subtle that after noticing the return value I actually deleted my comment thinking it was wrong, only to reinstate it after a more careful analysis.

Comment: "Note that there is a simpler way to find the middle index" - which was incorrect for quite a while (and may still be on 32-bit systems), since `left + right` could overflow when the vector is large enough. On 64-bit systems this is not an issue, of course.

Comment: @Cerberus Agreed, I'm pretty sure the code does the more complex thing intentionally precisely to avoid this kind of overflow. (Or was copy-pasted from somewhere where it was done intentionally.) The answer should at least mention that.

Comment: @Cerberus good point, I hadn't thought of that. Edited.